# Xquery and starts-with

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a problem with a Xquery.

I have this XML:

```
<peliculas>
<pelicula fechaEstreno='2007'>
    <titulo>Los Otros</titulo>
    <director>Alejandro Amenabar</director>
</pelicula>
<pelicula fechaEstreno='1986'>
    <titulo>Sangre Facil</titulo>
    <director>Ethan Coen</director>
</pelicula>
<pelicula fechaEstreno='1990'>
    <titulo>No es pais para viejos</titulo>
    <director>Ethan Coen</director>
    <director>Joel Coen</director>
</pelicula>
<pelicula fechaEstreno='2007'>
    <titulo>The Lovely Bones</titulo>
    <director>Peter Jackson</director>
</pelicula>
</peliculas>
```

I need to show the "titulo" where "director" starts-with 'A'. So I tried something this:

```
for $c in doc('C:\...\pelis.xml') //pelicula
where starts-with($c/director, 'A')
return
<pelicula>
{$c/titulo}
</pelicula>
```

But I have this error:

**Item expected, sequence found: (element director {...}, ...).**

I've used "ends-with" before and I thought the syntax it was similar for "starts-with" too, but It doesn't work.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the third `pelicula` element the XPath `$c/director` returns a *sequence* of two elements:

```
(
  <director>Ethan Coen</director>,
  <director>Joel Coen</director>
)
```

The function [`fn:starts-with(...)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-starts-with) on the other hand expects either the empty sequence or a single item as its first argument:

```
fn:starts-with($arg1 as xs:string?, $arg2 as xs:string?) as xs:boolean
```

Here is an example of what you can do instead:

```
for $c in doc('C:\...\pelis.xml')//pelicula
where
    some $director in $c/director
    satisfies starts-with($director, 'A')
return <pelicula>{
    $c/titulo
}</pelicula>
```

Using some XPath trickery you can even make it somewhat concise:

```
for $c in doc('C:\...\pelis.xml')//pelicula[director[starts-with(., 'A')]]
return <pelicula>{
    $c/titulo
}</pelicula>
```

Comment: That's a little more complicated than "ends-with"... I didn't know that "some... satisfies" exists. But It works. Thank you so much.

Comment: What makes you think that `fn:ends-with(...)` works differently? It does not allow sequences of more than one item either. I will add a more concise solution using XPath predicates to my answer.